# Connectivity issue from Power BI to Azure DataBricks

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-databricks

I am facing this error when i am trying to import data from Azure DataBricks to Power BI. The cluster is active only not terminated while trying to import. I am using UserName and Password as credentials.

It is throwing the following error

> ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][ThriftExtension] (14) Unexpected
> response from server during a HTTP connection: SSL_connect:
> certificate verify failed.
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtIzV.png)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

To resolve the above error,

> **Go to START >  ODBC DATA SOURCE ADMINSTRATOR > select your deriver > Configure > SSL options**

enable SSL, checking "Use Trusted store"
[image]

**OR**

To connect Databricks to PowerBI follow below steps.

Go to the cluster and click on **Advanced Options,** click on **jdbc/odbc**

create url **https://"ServerHostname"/"HTTP path"**  replace you values in quoted sections.
[image]

Generate personal access token

> **Go to Setting >> User Setting >> Access Token >> Generate new access token >>comment- PowerBI, lifetime-7 >> Generate**

[image]
**Save this token in notepad for future use**

**Now open PowerBI**

**Go to Get data >> More...>> other >> spark >> connect**

[image]

Now, copy-paste the **JDBC URL** (created in Step 1) in the **Server** field. Select **HTTP** as the **Protocol** and **DirectQuery** in the **Data Connectivity**  **mode**, and click **OK**:

[image]

In the next dialog box, type in **token** as the **User name** and paste **Token** value that we generated in Step 2 in the **Password** field. Then click **Connect**

**Now your databricks cluster connected to PowerBI**

[image]

Comment: Hi followed the same steps as mentioned using Go to the cluster and click on Advanced Options, click on jdbc/odbc

create url https://"ServerHostname"/"HTTP path" replace you values in quoted sections. Created the same and tried but still not working. But this time i am getting different error  Details: "ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][ThriftExtension] (14) Unexpected response from server during a HTTP connection: connect() failed: errno = 10060."

Comment: I up-ticked the answer since I have done this a bunch of times for clients.  Make sure you have an interactive cluster that is running.  There will be no response if the cluster is not running.  Also, a very small cluster might have response issues. This will work ...

Answer (score 0):

My company uses Zscaler and I turned it off temporarily and then refreshed the view and all worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).